# Android, Google-cast, "Error inflating class androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton"

Tags: android, exoplayer, google-cast

I have been trying to add google-cast to my Android app that plays videos using Exoplayer. The app has one single activity with`Theme.Leanback` theme and the same UI is used for both Phones and Android TV.

To add casting support on phones, I have modified in the player view and I added the cast button as below:

```
<androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
   android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="left"
   android:scaleY="0.8"
   android:scaleX="0.8"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
   android:visibility="visible" />
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE, PID: 10661
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76 in com.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE:layout/activity_player: Binary XML file line #76 in com.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE:layout/activity_player: Error inflating class androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76 in com.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE:layout/activity_player: Error inflating class androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE.fragment.PlayerFragment.onCreateView(PlayerFragment.java:162)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0
        at androidx.core.graphics.ColorUtils.calculateContrast(ColorUtils.java:161)
        at androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getControllerColor(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:177)
        at androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.getRouterThemeId(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:313)
        at androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouterThemeHelper.createThemedButtonContext(MediaRouterThemeHelper.java:107)
        at androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:153)
        at androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:149)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532) 
        at com.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE.fragment.PlayerFragment.onCreateView(PlayerFragment.java:162) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I have tried setting the background of the castbusston transparent as was suggested in few places online but that did not help.

I can have several other Image Button and Text Buttons that are working fine.

I tried using `<MediaRouteButton` instead of `<androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton`. This way the button will be showed and greyed out in the player layout however, when I try to intitize the cast context as below:

```
mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(mContext, mMediaRouteButton);

mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(mContext);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.MediaRouteButton cannot be cast to androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton

I have been puzzled by this issue for couple of days.  Thank you very much in advance for your kind comments and suggestion.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `primaryColor` of the app theme that I was using had transparency channel, ie, `#3d000000`. However MediaRouteButton that is taking the `primaryColor` of theme needs a color without transparency channel such as `#000000`. So I resolved the issue as follow:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback">
   <!--   Primary Color -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/defaultColor</item>
</style>
```

where I defined `<color name="defaultColor">#000000</color>`

Later on I encountered another issue that MediaCastButton can only be used with `AppCompat` decedent theme. The solution for me was to change the app theme to an `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme and modify it to look like `Theme.Leanback` as below:

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blackColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blackColor</item>

<!--        <item name="mediaRouteButtonTint">@color/whiteColor</item>-->

        <item name="baseCardViewStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.BaseCardViewStyle</item>
        <item name="imageCardViewStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ImageCardViewStyle</item>
        <item name="imageCardViewImageStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ImageCardView.ImageStyle</item>
        <item name="imageCardViewTitleStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ImageCardView.TitleStyle</item>
        <item name="imageCardViewContentStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ImageCardView.ContentStyle</item>
        <item name="imageCardViewBadgeStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ImageCardView.BadgeStyle</item>
        <item name="imageCardViewInfoAreaStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ImageCardView.InfoAreaStyle</item>

        <item name="browsePaddingStart">@dimen/lb_browse_padding_start</item>
        <item name="browsePaddingEnd">@dimen/lb_browse_padding_end</item>
        <item name="browsePaddingTop">@dimen/lb_browse_padding_top</item>
        <item name="browsePaddingBottom">@dimen/lb_browse_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="browseRowsMarginStart">@dimen/lb_browse_rows_margin_start</item>
        <item name="browseRowsMarginTop">@dimen/lb_browse_rows_margin_top</item>
        <item name="browseRowsFadingEdgeLength">@dimen/lb_browse_rows_fading_edge</item>

<!--            <item name="headersVerticalGridStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Headers.VerticalGridView</item>-->
<!--            <item name="headerStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Header</item>-->
<!--            <item name="sectionHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Header.Section</item>-->

        <item name="rowsVerticalGridStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Rows.VerticalGridView</item>
        <item name="rowHorizontalGridStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.HorizontalGridView</item>
        <item name="itemsVerticalGridStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.GridItems.VerticalGridView</item>

        <item name="browseTitleViewLayout">@layout/lb_browse_title</item>
        <item name="browseTitleTextStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Title.Text</item>
        <item name="browseTitleIconStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Title.Icon</item>
        <item name="browseTitleViewStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.TitleView</item>

        <item name="rowHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.Header</item>
        <item name="rowHeaderDescriptionStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.Header.Description</item>
        <item name="rowHoverCardTitleStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.HoverCardTitle</item>
        <item name="rowHoverCardDescriptionStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.HoverCardDescription</item>
        <item name="rowHeaderDockStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.HeaderDock</item>

<!--            <item name="searchOrbViewStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.SearchOrbViewStyle</item>-->


        <item name="detailsDescriptionTitleStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.DetailsDescriptionTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="detailsDescriptionSubtitleStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.DetailsDescriptionSubtitleStyle</item>
        <item name="detailsDescriptionBodyStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.DetailsDescriptionBodyStyle</item>
        <item name="detailsActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.DetailsActionButtonStyle</item>
        <!-- Attributes used for styling of a playback -->
        <item name="playbackPaddingStart">@dimen/lb_playback_controls_margin_start</item>
        <item name="playbackPaddingEnd">@dimen/lb_playback_controls_margin_end</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemPaddingStart">@dimen/lb_playback_media_row_horizontal_padding</item>

        <item name="playbackMediaListHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaListHeaderStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemRowStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemRowStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemSeparatorStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemSeparatorStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaListHeaderTitleStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaListHeaderTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemDetailsStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemDetailsStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemNumberViewFlipperStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemNumberViewFlipperStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemNumberViewFlipperLayout">@layout/lb_media_item_number_view_flipper</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemNumberStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemNumberStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemNameStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemNameStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackMediaItemDurationStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackMediaItemDurationStyle</item>

        <item name="playbackControlsButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackControlsButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackControlButtonLabelStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackControlLabelStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackControlsTimeStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackControlsTimeStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackControlsActionIcons">@style/Widget.Leanback.PlaybackControlsActionIconsStyle</item>
        <item name="playbackControlsAutoHideTimeout">@integer/lb_playback_controls_show_time_ms</item>
        <item name="playbackControlsAutoHideTickleTimeout">@integer/lb_playback_controls_tickle_timeout_ms</item>

        <item name="errorMessageStyle">@style/Widget.Leanback.ErrorMessageStyle</item>

        <item name="defaultSearchColor">@color/lb_default_search_color</item>
        <item name="defaultSearchIconColor">@color/lb_default_search_icon_color</item>
        <item name="defaultSearchBrightColor">?attr/defaultSearchColor</item>
        <item name="defaultSearchIcon">@drawable/lb_ic_in_app_search</item>

        <item name="defaultSectionHeaderColor">?attr/defaultSearchColor</item>

        <item name="overlayDimMaskColor">@color/lb_view_dim_mask_color</item>
        <item name="overlayDimActiveLevel">@fraction/lb_view_active_level</item>
        <item name="overlayDimDimmedLevel">@fraction/lb_view_dimmed_level</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the dependency that contains that class in your module's list of dependencies, such as:

```
implementation "androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.2.6"
```

(or another version as appropriate)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply. I have already included this dependency.

Comment: Do you know if MediaRouteButton can be added when using `Theme.Leanback`?

Comment: @krahimi: That would seem to be an odd combination. `Theme.Leanback` usually is used on a TV; `MediaRouteButton` would be used on a non-TV. Still, I would not expect a crash. Is there more to your stack trace, such as more "Caused by" sections, after the portion that you posted?

Comment: That is true, the app uses a single theme for both TV and Phones currently. No this the whole stack trace that I see.

Comment: I also tried context wrapper when inflating the View: `Context app_compat__context = new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
        inflater.cloneInContext(app_compat__context);` which I still see the exact same error.

Comment: Since the `MediaRouteButton` that you are using is in a library, you should be able to put a breakpoint in its constructor. See if you hit it, and see how far you can step through it. `InvocationTargetException` sometimes means that the class or method is not `public`, but that should not be the case here. It also sometimes means that you crashed somewhere in the invoked method -- ideally, that would show up as another "Caused by" section, but if you are not getting that, perhaps debugging will show where things are going wrong.

Comment: @ CommonsWare: Thanks so much. I just realized that part of stack trace was collapsed that I did not notice before. Sorry about that. I just updated the stack trace. I will also try to step through the code.

Comment: It appears that problem is caused here: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0`

Comment: That would seem to line up with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. If you remove that, do you get a different crash?

Comment: It turns out that the primary theme color needs to not have transparent channel. After making this change, it is working fine. Thank you very much for the hints

Comment: Great! You might want to post your own answer to your question, with the details of what you changed!

Comment: For sure, I will do. Thanks again